# PHPStorm doesn't pull or push

Tags: mercurial, phpstorm

I've recently switched from Netbeans to PHPStorm and I have weird issue with PHPStorm. Sometimes (really often) when I pull or push it shows that it is pulling/pushing but it never ends. I must restart PHPStorm, do it again and then it work.
I synchronize with bitbucket if that helps and I use mercurial.
PHPStorm doesn't show any errors.

Does anyone know what can cause this?

Comment: Did you try pull and push from shell?  If it works well then the problem is in PHPStorm.  Also I would check network connection with remote repository.  You can ping it and look on lags and loss rate.  Also PHPStorm could have "additional information" button or "view full output" button or something like that where you can look what actually happens.

Comment: I didn't try pushing from shell. Previously in Netbeans there wasn't any problems so I'm almost sure that it's something with PHPStorm but I can't figure out what. I'll try to do pushes from Terminal in PHPStorm as You suggested and check if it works.

Comment: Ok it looks like PHPStorm forgets password for my account on Bitbucket and when I want to pull or push it doesn't show popup to enter it again. When I was doing synchronization in terminal, as You suggested, it was pausing and asking me for password. So I think that it will be something with session remembering in PHPStorm.

Comment: So you use username/password for authentication on bitbucket?

Comment: Yes, I also installed plugin for that (called BitBucket) but nothing changed. :/ I think that I will report it as a bug to PHPStorm developers. Thanks for your time @Kirill.

Comment: Have a look at SSH, a lot of people prefer SSH over username/password.  With SSH you need to enter password for private key once on first pull or push.  Here is [manual](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Mercurial).

Comment: Thanks, I've just did that. For now, 2 test pushes are successfull. I will try use it till monday and check if it permanently works. On monday I will write about result.

Comment: Ok it works. Can You make answer from your comment so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at SSH, a lot of people prefer SSH over username/password. With SSH you need to enter password for private key once on first pull or push. Here is [manual](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Mercurial).